# Manipulate a powerpoint embedded in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-docs-api

I have an iframe with a powerpoint document embedded in it as follows:

```
<iframe src="//docs.google.com/gview?url=https://www.yourwebsite.com/powerpoint.ppt&embedded=true"
        style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

I want to be able to count the number of clicks and know the number of pages in powerpoint. I am using Angularjs, is it possible to use something like $scope.window.frame to get the properties of the slides.

Comment: Only if there is some google doc api for that. You can not access a cross domain iframe from main page using javascript due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: You can give [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) a read for further information

Comment: Many of the features that make Google Docs so successful are available through the API. This API lets you read and write documents programmatically so that you can integrate data from various sources leveraging the power of Google Docs. See [Google Docs API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/).

Comment: the doc is actually a powerpoint hosted in a sharepoint document library